# fail to start clojure.jar without build tool

Tags: clojure

I am restricted in a server env without internet access and not allowed to change any system settings /including env variables.

There are `clojure-1.10.1.jar` `core.specs.alpha-0.2.44.jar` `spec.alpha-0.2.176.jar` in local folder(windows 10).

when I try to run clojure.jar with `clojure.main` as entry point,here is the error:

```
 java -cp clojure-1.10.1.jar:spec.alpha-0.2.176.jar:core.specs.alpha-0.2.44.jar clojure.main
```

[image]

but if I run with `-jar` option on `clojure.jar`, it seems that java can find the entry point (while it can't find dependence for `spec`,`core.spec`.

```
java -jar clojure-1.10.1.jar
```

[image]
[image]

My question is, how can I start a repl via command line without leningen/boot/clj ?

Comment: Please include actual text, not screenshots of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original question did not mention that the asker was using the Windows operating system.  On a Linux or macOS system, this command works just fine if all of the 3 mentioned jar files are located in the current directory where the command is run:

```
java -cp clojure-1.10.1.jar:spec.alpha-0.2.176.jar:core.specs.alpha-0.2.44.jar clojure.main
```

If I then remove the file clojure-1.10.1.jar from that directory, and run the command again, I get the same error message as you show in the question.  So it is advisable with that error message to double check that those files are actually in the current directory where that java command is being executed, or some other directory.

On a Windows system, the semicolon (;) character is the standard separator character used to separate multiple file names or directory names in a list of such things, not the colon (:), so this command works for Windows:

```sh
    java -cp clojure-1.10.1.jar;spec.alpha-0.2.176.jar;core.specs.alpha-0.2.44.jar clojure.main
```

See the discussion at the following link for why that difference in separator characters exists between Windows versus Linux/macOS: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-Java-classpath-separator-a-semicolon-on-Windows-and-a-colon-on-other-OSs-Is-there-a-certain-reason-for-Windows

Comment: I'm feeling something wrong with windows maybe.. I tried 3 machines ( one of them is clean, hasn't install any lein/clj previously ) . it has same error message . (can not fin clojure.main )

Comment: On a Windows 10 machine where I tried typing the command above in a cmd.exe window, I got the same error message.  If I replaced the : separators between the JAR file names with semicolon instead, as in the command below, it works.  I believe this is one of those differences with Java on Windows vs. Java on other operating systems:  "java -cp clojure-1.10.1.jar:spec.alpha-0.2.176.jar:core.specs.alpha-0.2.44.jar clojure.main"

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-Java-classpath-separator-a-semicolon-on-Windows-and-a-colon-on-other-OSs-Is-there-a-certain-reason-for-Windows for some background on this Windows difference, it is not just for Java, but for many things on Windows where you specify a list of files/directories.

Comment: @andy_fingerhut I suggest editing the relevant information into your answer. Comments are ephemeral.

Comment: Edited answer so that it includes all information I know to be useful that appeared in any comment.